# what's the vascular cambium?

Tags: botany

is the vascular cambium equivalent to interfascular cambium or intrafascular cambium?

isn't the vascular cambium similar to the intrafascular cambium because both occur inside the vascular bundle

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. 1) You should chose a title that is much more specific. Don't be afraid if your title already states most of what you have to write in your post. 2) You should always limit your posts to only 1 question (I am not qualified to judge whether the fact that the current post contain two questions makes it too broad or not). 3) As the questions sounds like homework questions (although you tell those are not homework questions) you should tell us your thoughts and your attempt to answer the question. Knowing what you know and think make the answers much more helpful for the OP.

Comment: okay i will edit my post.